# Difference between two dates in R for different groups when running a survival analysis

Tags: r, date, difference

I am creating my dataset to carry out a survival analysis. I have these variables:
`CASE_ID`, `i_birthdate_c`, `i_deathdate_c`, `difftime_c`,  `event1`, `enddate`.

- `Case_id` = unique ID
- `birthdate` = subject, enters observation
- `deathdate` = when they died
- `difftime_c` is the time from birth to death
- `event1` = censoring variable indicating death has or has not occurred
- `enddate` = when all subjects will be censored if the event has not occurred.

I am trying to calculate the time from `i_birthdate_c` to `enddate` (12/31/2013). I want this value to be finally populated in my `difftime_c` variable if the event1 = 0. As it stands, I have the time from  `i_birthdate_c` to `i_deathdate_c` for when `event1` = 1.

What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this in R with the existing code I have below? I keep striking out with my if statements.

Model:

```
newdata$difftime_c <- difftime(newdata$deathdate_c,newdata$birthdate_c,units="weeks")
```

Comment: You need to provide a snippet of your data as well as a desired output. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for a guide.

Comment: livebornheart[livebornheart$event1==1, 46] <-livebornheart    [livebornheart$event1==1, 39] #conditional formatting for when event==1
 
    livebornheartdata[livebornheartdata$event1==0, 46]     <-livebornheartdata[livebornheartdata$event1==0, 44] #conditional formatting for when event==0

Comment: Hey Abdou, thanks for responding, but after a bit of trial and error, I got it working. ;)